# XPath Like Regex One or More

Tags: xpath

I want to select something is a child of 1 to N of the same kind of nodes nested. The xml would look something like this:

```
<Folder>
   <Folder>
      <Folder>
         <Folder>
            <File></File>
         </Folder>
      </Folder>
   </Folder>
</Folder>
```

or

```
<Folder>
   <File></File>
</Folder>
```

The Files I am selecting must be a child of folder and none of those folders can have anything other than a folder as an ancestor. I don't want to use descendants to get all Files only to check each of their ancestors. I would rather follow the Folder chain and then stop at any Files directly after a Folder. Something like regex's + is what I'm looking for (./Folder+/File) but I don't know what that syntax is if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath has no "repeating axis" construct; you'll need to use a combination of the [XPath axes](http://www.xmlplease.com/axis) and predicate conditions to achieve your desired result.

Here's an expression that gets all `File` elements that are children of `Folder` elements, and then checks that the `Folder` element's ancestors are all `Folder` elements:

```
//Folder/File[fn:not(ancestor::*/fn:local-name(.) != "Folder")]
```

Comment: Sweet this should be good. The only problem I see is if there are a lot of //Folders/Files that don't have only Folders as ancestors this could be slower than the way I wanted to do it but if that can't be done it can't be done. Thank you.